# What can make a DLL fail AOT compilation?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

*(This similar to another question I asked, but that one was focused on disabling AOT. This is focused on diagnosing the root cause.)*

I'm working on a Xamarin Forms project. For the past few weeks, I've been focused on the iOS code and haven't paid much attention to the Android side. This week, I got a more Android-specific issue so I tried deployment. Deployment always fails with the message "Could not AOT the assembly: foo.dll". "foo.dll" is an internal assembly made by another team.

No one else on my team is having this problem, but they develop on Windows machines. I'm on mac OS Sierra, and I'm suspicious something in the build toolchain's currently incompatible. But there were also a host of Xamarin updates before this started, so I don't know if they're innocent either.

Over time, I managed to isolate this to something related to the Xamarin Studio 6.1.x release cycle. Anyone on my team who upgrades starts getting this error, on both Windows and Mac OS.

We can temporarily address this by disabling AOT in the project via a .csproj tag, but our application has displayed significant performance increases when it's enabled. So I'd like to figure out why this DLL fails AOT compilation, and fix it. But I have no clue how to progress.

What can cause this failure? Why wouldn't it happen with the iOS version of the DLL? Why is it specific to Xamarin Studio 6.1?

(I'm currently running Xamarin Studio 6.0.2 (build 73) on OSX 10.12.0. I have Xamarin.iOS 9.8.2.22 and Xamarin.Android 6.1.2.21. Upgrading from these to anything in the 6.1.x cycle seems to trigger the problem.)

Comment: Check your project references and verify the "foo.dll" location, maybe is missing or incorrect.